# CHIRPS data for variable in a loop using R

Tags: r

This program must download the CHIRPS data according to the detail entered, and then assign each year of information in a variable 'nc' and export it as '.csv'. However, the code does not work and I received the message "R Session Failed Failed Error" in RStudio.

```
### Importing libraries
library(parallel)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(heavyRain)

### Working directory
setwd("D:/data-science_hydrology/g8/")

### Download CHIRPS monthly
data_CHIRPS <- getCHIRPS(region = "global",
                         format = "netcdf",
                         tres = "daily",
                         sres = 0.25,
                         begin = as.Date("1981-01-01"),
                         end = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                         dsn = "data/chirps_daily",
                         overwrite = T,
                         cores = 1)

### THIS CRASH ME RSTUDIO
for (i in 1981:1982){
  nc <- paste("nc", i, sep = "")
  assign(nc, brick(paste("data/chirps_daily/chirps-v2.0.", i, ".days_p25.nc", sep ="")))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should *never* use `assign`; rather store the objects you create in a list. You can nornally do that like this

```
library(raster)
y <- 1981:1982
ff <- paste0("data/chirps_daily/chirps-v2.0.", y, ".days_p25.nc")
nc <- lapply(ff, brick)
names(nc) <- y
```

That will probably give the same error, most likely because of a corrupted file. To find out which, use a loop to see where it fails.

```
nc <- list()
for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
  print(ff[i]); flush.console()
  nc[[i]] <- brick(ff[i])
}
```

And then re-download the bad file and try again.